# Uses for cpp struct variables passed in templates

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures, struct

I just want to ask if there are any uses for passing variables in cpp as template arguments

```
template<int a> struct foo {
    int x = a;
};

int main() {
    foo<2> bar;
    std::cout << bar.x;
}
```

Something like this compiles, works and `cout`'s 2 but the same thing can be done by doing

```
struct foo {
    int x;
    foo(int a) : x(a) {}
};

int main() {
    foo bar(2);
    std::cout << bar.x;
}
```

So what is the point of using variables in template arguments? I can also see a big flaw in using the first method: the variable `a` uses memory and isn't destructed after `x` is changed, as it would be after the constructor is called in the second example. It might be helpful if you showed some reasonable uses for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass a variable through a template argument, it can be used in compile time.

For example, if you need to create a statically sized array in your class, you could use the template argument to pass the size of your array:

```
template <int TSize>
class Foo {
    [...] // Do whatever you need to do with mData.
private:
    std::array<int, TSize> mData;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many uses for constants in template parameters.

### Static Sizes

This is how you would start implementing something like a `std::array`.

```cpp
template <typename T, size_t SIZE>
struct Array {
    T data[SIZE];
}
```

Template parameters are always usable in a `constexpr` context, so they can be used as sizes for statically sized arrays.

### Providing Compile-Time Parameters to Algorithms

Another use is parametrizing algorithms like in the following code sample.
We have a `uint32_t` in `ARGB` order but to store it in a file, we might need to reorder it to `BGRA` or `RGBA`. We know the order at compile time, so we could use an `ArgbOrder` template variable.

```cpp
enum class ArgbOrder { ARGB, RGBA, BGRA };

struct ChannelOffsets {
    unsigned a;
    unsigned r;
    unsigned g;
    unsigned b;
};

// and we can get a constexpr lookup table from this enum
constexpr ChannelOffsets byteShiftAmountsOf(ArgbOrder format)
{
    ...
}

template <ArgbOrder order>
void encodeArgb(uint32_t argb, uint8_t out[4])
{
    // We can generate the shift amounts at compile time.
    constexpr detail::ChannelOffsets shifts = shiftAmountsOf(order);
    out[0] = static_cast<u8>(argb >> shifts.a);
    out[1] = static_cast<u8>(argb >> shifts.r);
    out[2] = static_cast<u8>(argb >> shifts.g);
    out[3] = static_cast<u8>(argb >> shifts.b);
}

void example() {
    encodeArgb<ArgbOrder::BGRA>(12345);
}
```

In this example, we can select the appropriate lookup table at compile time and have zero runtime cost. All that needs to happen at runtime is 4 shifts.

### Feature Toggles

We can use `bool` template variables to toggle features in our code, like for example:

```cpp
template <bool handleZeroSpecially>
int div(int x, int y) {
    if constexpr (handleZeroSpecially) {
        return y == 0 ? 0 : x / y;
    }
    else {
        return x / y;
    }
}
```